# Filtering according to the locale 'de_DE'

Tags: php, taxonomy

I already have a filter to show on archive pages the terms of the taxonomy "tipologia" according to the locale = 'de_DE'. I need a similar filter to show in german the same taxonomy terms inside a selector in the search box. I dont know how to replace some elements like get_the_archive_title
Here is my filter:

```
add_filter('get_the_archive_title', function( $title_archive) {
$locale = get_locale();
if ('de_DE' == $locale ) {
$title_archive_de = get_term_meta( get_queried_object()->term_id, 'function_tipologia', true );

 if ( ! empty( $title_archive_de )) {
    return $title_archive_de;
 } else {
    return $title_archive;
 }
} else {
 return $title_archive;
}

}, 10, 2 );
```

My selector in the search box is:

```
$select = $wp_query->get('tipologia');
$select = '' == $select ? 0 : $select;
$taxonomy = wp_dropdown_categories([
'hierarchical' => false,
'name' => 'tipologia',
'taxonomy' => 'tipologia',
'selected' => $select,
'show_option_all' => esc_html__('Typology', 'sacconicase'),
'value_field' => 'slug',
'echo' => false
 ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve filtering according to the locale `de_DE` for the taxonomy terms displayed in the search box selector, you can use a similar approach as your archive title filter.

```
add_filter('wp_dropdown_categories', function( $output, $args ) {
    $locale = get_locale();
    if ('de_DE' == $locale && $args['taxonomy'] == 'tipologia') {
        // Modify output for German locale and 'tipologia' taxonomy
        $terms = get_terms([
            'taxonomy' => 'tipologia',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ]);

        if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
            $output = '<select name="' . esc_attr($args['name']) . '">' . "\n";
            $output .= '<option value="0">' . esc_html__('Typology', 'sacconicase') . '</option>' . "\n";
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $output .= '<option value="' . esc_attr($term->slug) . '">' . esc_html($term->name) . '</option>' . "\n";
            }
            $output .= '</select>' . "\n";
        }
    }

    return $output;
}, 10, 2);
```